# Turning spaces into underscores in CSV headers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, hash

I'm trying to upload rows from a CSV file into my database, but the spaces in the headers keep messing me up. So for example, the header will be "Order Item Id" and I want the hash key to be "order_item_id". Here's what my code looks like now:

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers:true, :header_converters => lambda { |h| h.try(:downcase) },  col_sep: ';') do |row|
  product_hash = row.to_hash

  product = OrderCsv.where(id: product_hash["id"])

  if product.count ==1
    product.first.update_attributes(product_hash)
  else

    user.order_csvs.create!(product_hash)
  end

end
```

I've tried editing the product_hash with product_hash.keys.each { |k| k =  "..." }
   but it doesn't do anything. I've also tried creating a header converter like the one that does the downcasing, but I wasn't able to make that work either. Sorry if this is a newb question, but I've been looking everywhere for an answer and none of them have been working for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the replacement after the downcase, in the `:header_converters`, like this:

```
lambda { |h| h.try(:downcase).try(:gsub,' ', '_') }
```

Comment: You could also use a modifier `if` instead of the `try` chain, i.e. `h.downcase.gsub(' ', '_') if h` or maybe even `h.to_s.downcase.gsub(' ', '_')` if an empty header is okay.

Comment: So I used this and it works, but now I'm getting an "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8" error when I try to upload a file. The result is that only the first row is uploaded from the file. Is it possible that this is messing with the carriage return/new row? I've never gotten these errors before

Comment: I don't think your problem has anything to do with the new code, most likely it is an issue with the file and you didn't see that before because it didn't get this far (because of the problem with the headers).

Comment: Possibly, I was able to fix it by encoding it to UTF-8 explicitly with :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1'   I never had this problem before this change though, and I was able to upload all the data by manually removing the spaces in the headers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
product_hash = { "Order Item Id" => 2 }
product_hash = product_hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|
  h[k.parameterize.underscore] = v
end
puts product_hash # {"order_item_id"=>2}
```

Comment: This also works, thank you. However, it's causing the same "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8" error that the CSV header code causes. Something about replacing all spaces in the header with underscores is messing with the ability to get to the next row - it's only uploading the first row of the file now

Comment: For anyone who's reading this and happens to run into the UTF-8 error after making this change, i fixed it by encoding to UTF-8 with :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1'

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else stumble upon this question you can make use of `:symbol` header_converter

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/CSV.html#HeaderConverters

> The header String is downcased, spaces are replaced with underscores, non-word characters are dropped, and finally to_sym() is called.

**Example:**

```
CSV.foreach(csv_path, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
  # do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to convert a hash with keys containing spaces to a hash with keys containing underscores, you can do the following

```
hash_with_spaces = {"order item id" => '1', "some other id" => '2'}
new_hash = hash_with_spaces.inject({}) do |h, (k, v)| 
  h[k.gsub(' ', '_')] = v ; h
end

new_hash
#=> {"order_item_id"=>"1", "some_other_id"=>"2"}
```